# Selecting rows within N days of range of certain records

Tags: sql, oracle11gr2

I need to get the records which are in a range of 20 days following a certain process.

There is a table `medical` that contains data as shown below:

Here is the [SQLFIDDLE:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0d9c0/1)

[image]

Rule is : If Group is A3, then all operations within 20 days `(to the same patient in the same hospital)` are free of charge.

So, here all the operations until 09.02.2013 should be free of charge. (20.01.2013 + 20 days)

Question: How can I retrieve all the records within 20 days following the day an A3 group process is applied?

Comment: you can make a nested query and do the date math, or you can look up LAG functions and walk the rows until you pass the time period.

Comment: I tried the lag function bu it doesnt not allow time intervals, only row intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the liberty of changing the datatype of dat and changed the name of group to groupe.

```
WITH modified_medical
     AS (SELECT hospital, pid, dat
           FROM medical
          WHERE groupe = 'A3')
  SELECT *
    FROM medical a, modified_medical b
   WHERE     b.hospital = a.hospital
         AND b.pid = a.pid
         AND a.dat BETWEEN b.dat AND b.dat + 20
ORDER BY a.hospital, a.pid, a.dat;
```

Sample fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/06049/1).